# Kemp returning 520 http error when I try to connect to sub that is http using https

Tags: reverse-proxy, load-balancing, https, http

I hope you're doing great so; recently, I started using kemp as a load balancer for my server, and everything works fine when the service (real server) comes already with a self-signed SSL from the host, but when I try to add a new real server that its default is HTTP and doesn't have HTTPS when I try to access it the same way I do with the other the browser returns a 520 error.

I heard some terms online and from the docs saying that I should reverse proxy for getting an SSL cert from my domain, but I don't know exactly what to do.

I searched online for my problem, but I don't know exactly what to search for, so I didn't find anything, and I was hoping someone from here could help me out.

**The VIP and Real Servers**

[image]

**The VIP Config**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**The Real Server Config**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share some screenshots off your kemp config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by following the steps below:

1. Created a new VIP
2. Added a new real server with the IP and port of the service
3. Activated SSL Acceleration in this new VIP
4. Added the IP and Port of this new VIP to the other VIP

This is probably not ideal, but it worked, and since I'm not expecting other people besides me, entering should not cause any delay problems.